# How to get GUID of a subfolder in a document library programmatically

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, guid, document-library

Okay, here is the scenario...
I have created a subfolder in a document library, and when an item is added to the document library, i want to do some processing on the document and then move the item to the subfolder, say MySubFolder. For that purpose, i will be using this statement

```
SPListItem folder = this.workflowProperties.List.Folders[];
```

but the Folders[] collection will take either an int index or a guid. SInce i am doing it in a workflow, I dont know how to get the guid of the folder here. Please note that I cannot use the url to get the GUID here because the same workflow is applied to a number of document libraries and I have the MySubFolder subfolder in all of them, so giving the url seems a bit tacky here i think.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Sharepoint here right now, but you should be able to do:

```
Guid folderId = Guid.Empty;
foreach (SPFolderCollection folder in YourList.Folders)
{
    if (folder.Name == "MySubFolder")
    {
        folderId = folder.UniqueId;
        break;
    }
}
```

Or, into your event handler, build your folder URL:

```
public override void ItemDeleting(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    Uri folderAddress = new Uri(properties.BeforeUrl, "MySubFolder");
    SPFolder folder = yourWeb.GetFolder(folderAddress.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your code, I was receiving an error saying YourList.Folder returns SPListItems and it couldnt b cast as SPFolderCollection.
But your solution definitely put me on the right track and i found the solution below:) thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing the following:

```
Guid folderId = Guid.Empty;
SPFolder spFolder = web.Folders[this.workflowProperties.List.Title].SubFolders["MySubFolder"];
folderId=spFolder.UniqueId;
```